# Express $\sin3\phi$, with the help of De Moivre formula, in terms of $\sin\phi$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

> Express $\sin3\phi$, with the help of De Moivre formula, into $\sin\phi$.

So far I got

$$\sin 3 \phi  = 3\sin \phi \cos^2 \phi  + \sin ^3  \phi
$$

I'm honestly not sure if I have to include $3\sin \phi \cos^2 \phi$ into the answer, considering the question didn't ask me to express it into $\sin\phi$ *and*  $\cos\phi$.

Comment: I  fixed the markup of formulas, which appeared to be generated by some weird editor.  See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Comment: Are the downvotes for the bad formatting? The question seems okay and the poster has shown their work.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are asked to express in terms of $\sin\phi$ only, you should get rid of the cosine. $$\cos^2\phi = 1-\sin^2\phi$$ does the trick.